# Formatar valor para R$ no gráfico Chart JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartjs

Bom a algum tempo atrás, um usuário aqui do STACK me ajudou a solucionar um problema com formatação de moeda no gráfico Chart JS. Porém achei um novo problema.

Com a ajuda do Sergio conseguimos colocar o trafico para exibir valores em reais (R$). Porém quando coloco 2 resultados para ser exibidos a formatação não funciona.

Vou postar os 2 código aqui através do JSFiddle, pois ele não funciona aqui no STACK.

Segue o código funcionando a formatação, porem com apenas 1 resultado:
http://jsfiddle.net/8xkk4gps/2

E aqui segue o código com 2 resultados, e a formatação não funciona.
http://jsfiddle.net/8xkk4gps/6/

Bom se alguém puder me ajudar, dês de já agradeço.

Comment: O problema é o mesmo que essa outra pergunta, fechei como duplicada. Se quiseres podes dar o teu `+1` lá :) O teu jsFiddle ficaria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/8xkk4gps/7/

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho aqui.